# Display notification at a specific time

Tags: java, android-studio, android-notifications, android-calendar, android-switch

I have currently created a notification which displays no problem when the switch is checked, however I want to create an if statement to set a current time of when the notification will be displayed. I have tried the below however the notification doesn't display at the 3:30pm when tested, am I missing anything or how can I do this?

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean notificationSwitchisChecked) {
      if(notificationSwitchisChecked){
           Calendar.getInstance();
           if (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY == 15 && Calendar.MINUTE == 30 && Calendar.SECOND == 0){
             sendNotification(); // this method displays the notification no problem when checked
                }
           }
```

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. You need to look into using either AlarmManager: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms or WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager. Read about them and pick whichever best suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you learn about event listeners and check out the stack answer below:

[Current time/date event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797904/current-time-date-event-listener)

Comment: It is android studio I need; unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.